# Storing a Binary Tree in computer memory

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

The table below represents a tree stored in a computer's memory. Each node of the tree contains three cells. The first cell contains the data to be stored; the second cell contains a pointer to the first cell's left child, and the third cell contains a pointer to the first cell's right child. A value of 00 as a pointer represents the nil pointer. A separate variable points to the root of the tree. The root of the tree is the cell that starts at 4F; that is, the variable that holds the root pointer has the value 4F. Fill in the resulting tree. Draw a picture of the resulting tree. (One way to draw a picture of a binary tree using  typewriter graphics is by using  / to indicate a left pointer and \ to indicate a right pointer. You can see an example of that in the next problem.)

```
Address    Contents

40        A1
41        00
42        00
43        B2
44        00
45        00
46        D4
47        49
48        00
49        C3
4A        00
4B        00
4C       E5
4D       43
4E        40
4F        F6
50        46
51        4C
```

I have an idea how to solve this problem.  But does anybody have any idea to solve this problem

Comment: just follow the pointers :) but where are the three cells? there is only one listed under the contents column

Comment: Here is my analysis on this matter.  I think the cells ending in "00" are supposed to represent the end of a link list.   The first cell is supposed represent data, the second cell a left child and the third a right child. But I'm not quite sure what he means by data. I would ask him, but he is really bad with his emails.  That's my guess.

Comment: What's the problem I have asked homework questions before. The only differences on this one   is I couldn't give a solution because I didn't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

[image]

It was generated from this Python code, using `python tree.py | dot -T png a.png`

```
data = """
40        A1
41        00
42        00
43        B2
44        00
45        00
46        D4
47        49
48        00
49        C3
4A        00
4B        00
4C       E5
4D       43
4E        40
4F        F6
50        46
51        4C""".split("\n")

data = [line.split() for line in filter(None, data)]
data = dict(map((lambda x: int(x, 16)), line) for line in data)

def print_tree(data, p):
    print '  n%x [label="%d"];' % (p, data[p])
    for c in data[p+1], data[p+2]:
        if not c: continue
        print_tree(data, c)
        print '  n%x -> n%x;' % (p, c)

print 'digraph tree {'
print_tree(data, 0x4f)
print '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

First node is at address `4F`, so the root node is `[value=F6, leftChildAddr=46, rightChildAddr=4C]`. Then read the left child node which is 3 bytes long and starts at the address `46`. Then read the 3 bytes of the right child node. And go down like this until you don't have any more pointer to follow (end nodes can have a value, but second and third bytes of end nodes are null).

Comment: Damn I see what u mean. I don't know how I over looked that. Thanks!! :-)